# QGIS warning ballpark transform from

Tags: qgis

Whenever I open the one project I've ever done in QGIS, I get a warning at the top of the screen about "Used a ballpark transform from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:26916". I presume this means I've done something wrong, I'm thinking that at least one layer doesn't have the correct projection (should be NAD83 UTM 16N). However, under Project>Properties, it lists the correct projection. I've also selected all of the layers, Set CRS to the correct projection and still I get this warning when I open QGIS.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34983 ? May it be an extent problem?

Answer (score 5):

To convert from EPSG:4326 (i.e. WGS84, geographic coordinates) to your target projection ([EPSG:26916](http://epsg.io/26916)), there are a variety of possible transformations. These are listed under "possible transformations" on that website. Under the hood, a tool called PROJ is being used to perform the mathematical calculations needed to perform this projection. It tries to find the [best available](http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/advanced_examples.html?highlight=best_available) candidate transformation. The candidate that gets picked depends on [a number of criteria](https://proj.org/operations/operations_computation.html#filtering-and-sorting-of-coordinate-operations). One of these criteria is an [*area of interest*](http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/advanced_examples.html#area-of-interest), with higher-specifity transformations getting priority over lower-specifity. It is possible that you have data that is outside of all areas of interest for all possible transformations, and so none of the highly accurate transformations, those that depend on installed "grids" for datum transformation, are selected to reproject your data; and PROJ falls back to a "ballpark" transformation of last resort.

Sometimes a transformation is just impossible and the data is not transformed, other times it just means the final coordinates are not as highly accurate as they could have been if they were actually located within the expected region. The "ballpark" transformation is in some sense a "null" transformation where an assumption is made that both input and output coordinate reference systems share the same datum.

Solutions:

- Try a different projection that covers a larger area, probably a global one.
- Remove/filter out data that is not within the area of applicability of EPSG:26916, i.e. data not in Canada/CONUS.
- Ignore the error, especially if you don't need extremely accurate coordinate transformation — e.g. almost all large scale cartographic applications at contintental scale. I recall that the worst error you could introduce is on the order of hundreds of metres.

Comment: Disclaimer: I've only recently got my feet wet with some advanced aspects of coordinate transformations, and some of my information may be wrong. I reconigse this error, and I know QGIS depends on PROJ, but do not have any knowledge of how QGIS may do something special. If there's something amiss in my answer, please edit it or contribute a new answer.