# Ballpark Transform Occured QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I get the ballpark-only transform when I try to map Orland, FL shapefile but I don't get any matches. The default is NAD83 EPSG-4269. When QGIS suggests that I use EPSG-2236, I can't find it in the properties options.

Comment: More information please on your data, what you're doing, and what's not working.

Comment: perhaps this will help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357269/qgis-warning-ballpark-transform-from